# Null object reference JSONArray and JSONObject

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I am trying fetch some ID from JSON.
Php code works correctly, i am getting my information from SQL database, but when i am trying to parse JSON array or JSON object i am catching following errors:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

**Errors caused by strings:**
int success = jsonObject.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);

**and**

movies = jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA);

```
public class MovieListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String KEY_DATA = "data";
        private static final String KEY_MOVIE_ID = "intDocID";
        private static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/ld/";
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movieList;
        private ListView movieListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_listing);
        movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieList);
        new FetchMoviesAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    private class FetchMoviesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpJsonParser httpJsonParser = new HttpJsonParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = httpJsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    BASE_URL + "fetchOrder.php", "GET", null);
            try {
                int success = jsonObject.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);

                JSONArray movies;
               if (success == 1) {

                    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
                    movies = jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA);
                    //Iterate through the response and populate movies list
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        Integer movieId = movie.getInt(KEY_MOVIE_ID);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(KEY_MOVIE_ID, movieId.toString());
                        movieList.add(map);
                   }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    populateMovieList();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    private void populateMovieList() {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MovieListingActivity.this, movieList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{KEY_MOVIE_ID},
                new int[]{R.id.movieId,});
        // updating listview
        movieListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Call MovieUpdateDeleteActivity when a movie is clicked
        movieListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Check for network connectivity
                if (CheckNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                    String movieId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieId))
                            .getText().toString();
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    //        MovieUpdateDeleteActivity.class);
                    //intent.putExtra(KEY_MOVIE_ID, movieId);
                    //startActivityForResult(intent, 20);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MovieListingActivity.this,
                            "Unable to connect to internet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 20) {
            // If the result code is 20 that means that
            // the user has deleted/updated the movie.
            // So refresh the movie listing
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is HttpJsonParser class:**

```
public class HttpJsonParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    static JSONArray jarr = null;


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      Map<String, String> params) {

        try {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            URL urlObj;
            String encodedParams = "";
            if (params != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            if (builder.build().getEncodedQuery() != null) {
                encodedParams =  builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            }
            if ("GET".equals(method)) {
                url = url + "?" + encodedParams;
                urlObj = new URL(url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);


            } else {
                urlObj = new URL(url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(encodedParams.getBytes().length));
                urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(encodedParams.getBytes());
            }


            urlConnection.connect();
            is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            /*
            json.substring(1);
            json.substring(0,json.length());
            */
            jarr = new JSONArray(json);
            jObj = jarr.getJSONObject(1);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Here is fetchOrder.php:

```
{"success":1,"data":[{"intDocID":2}]}
```

Comment: check if(movie.has(KEY_MOVIE_ID)){}

Comment: Your FetchMoviesAsyncTask parses the jsonObject correctly so the only reason I see for getting NPE is because the server side code returns a json structure that is different from the one you expect.

Comment: @Lino but how it can be? i got normal json in php and as you saying i got correct Async, JSONArray, JSONObject etc in android code. Where is error between server side and android code?

Comment: do you know which is the value of the `json` variable inside the `HttpJsonParser` class?